# Alternate lines when TextView breaks

Tags: android, textview

I'm creating a chord app. My problem is that when the lyric is bigger than the screen size, it break and becomes two lines.
**Example**:

A                   C                        D                  A

`Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey`

**Becomes**:

A                   C

D                  A

`Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey`

`Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey`

**Desired**:

A                   C

`Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey`

D                  A

`Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey Hey`

There's a way to break the lines and alternate them to keep always one line with the lyric and another with the keys when the textview breaks?

Answer (score 0):

Put inside a `LinearLayout` with `vertical` orientation 2 TextViews: one for the chord and one for the lyric that correspond to that chord. This way chord and lyric will stay together up and down.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lyric"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="lyric"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This way the same thing will still happens. They both gonna break together and be  2 lines each one instead of alternated.

Comment: No it doesn't. I guess you understand that the above layout contains only 1 chord and the corresponding lyrics. For each chord you have to create separate layout and all of them in a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation. Unless you know how  to make all this work with a container like a RecyclerView.